# Online SharePoint Columns Validation in SharePoint list

Tags: column-validation

I have two columns for validation. " Vehicle Model" and "Vehicle Registration Number" and are choice columns. I want the vehicles to be validated by the Vehicle Model when selecting the vehicle Registration Number to stop the user from using the wrong vehicle to Vehicle Model and to send a message to the user for imputing correct information. see the screenshot of the two columns ?

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't enough information to be able to provide you an answer. Please provide more details about how the validation should be done and what you've tried (edit your question). Thanks!

Comment: on the two columns above  i want to configure them with column validation. example, if a user selected a vehicle registration 73 CD 178  a validation of the vehicle model (TOYOTA PRADO) should be done in other to calculate the fuel KM/L

Comment: Sorry, that's still not enough to go on. That's the result, not the rules. How do you know that registration goes with that vehicle model? Are you looking for a validation error or are you wanting to restrict choices?